# Generate getters and setters for PHP in Enterprise Architect

Tags: php, uml, getter-setter, enterprise-architect, generated-code

I'm using Enterprise Architect to make a UML class diagram and generate PHP5 code. How can I generate getter and setter methods for a certain class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `<<Property>>` Stereotype to the attribute you want to create Getters and Setters for.

For further reference see

- http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/modeling/attributes.htm and
- http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/modeling/createprop.htm